# From four red, five green, and six yellow apples, how many selections of eight apples are possible if three of each color are to be selected?

Tags: probability

How do you do this question? If there were 9 apples it would be easy, but not sure how to select 8, if we have 3 colours from each.

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn't say "**at most** three of each color"?

Comment: @Arthur yep, that was it. The answer should be 6000 right?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's simply not possible so the answer is zero?

Comment: Thank you, seems like it was a trick question then